# Bullet symbol in TextView reverses/mirrors text in Android Preview Window API 18

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a simple TextView in my layout. I want to add bullet symbol (to mark some of hidden text in it). Issue is that text is kind of reversed after adding bullet symbol. Example:

xml: android:text="•••• •••• ••••  1234"

preview window of API 18: "1234 •••• •••• ••••"

This happens on API 18 ( API 17 displays correctly). This happens only if there are no letters in textview.

What could be the cause and how can I fix this?

Comment: Ignore the preview window for the moment. When you run this on a device or emulator, what happens?

Comment: Ok. Emulator does indeed show it correctly. So this might be a preview window bug.